# How to send mail using PHPMailer with localhost SMTP to gmail?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I try to send email using PHPMailer, here my code:

```
require '/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mailltoadm = new PHPMailer;
$mailltoadm->isSMTP();     
$mailltoadm->Host = 'localhost';  
$mailltoadm->SMTPAuth = true;     
$mailltoadm->Username = 'admin@queenshifa.com';  
$mailltoadm->Password = 'mypasswordhere';  
$mailltoadm->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mailltoadm->From = $emaillogin; 
$mailltoadm->FromName = $userloginname; 
$mailltoadm->addAddress($mastermaill, $name_store);
$mailltoadm->addAddress($mastermaill);  
$mailltoadm->addReplyTo($emaillogin, $userloginname);
$mailltoadm->WordWrap = 50;
$mailltoadm->isHTML(true);  
$mailltoadm->Subject = 'New Order '. $name_store;
$mailltoadm->Body    = $finishorder; 
$mailltoadm->AltBody = convert_html_to_text($finishorder);
if(!$mailltoadm->send()) 
{
   echo 'Mailer to admin Error: ' . $mailltoadm->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
   echo 'Message to admin has been sent';
}
```

Why email send to @yahoo.com success, but not send to @gmail.com ?
can any one help me please.

Comment: Why is all the text of your question bold?

Comment: Did you get any error messages, either in PHP or in the SMTP server's log? Most likely Google's servers are rejecting the mail on spam or similar grounds.

Comment: are you sure you are able to send Mail from localhost to yahoo.com

Comment: no error in php, just show up "Message to admin has been sent", but I can't cek error in SMTP because I don't know where I can fine the SMTP server log in CPanel.

Answer (score 0):

If you can really receive emails on @yahoo and don't have them @gmail it simple means that Google blocks your emails. You should definitely check your spam folder on Gmail because your emails probably are there.

Comment: of course I receive email on yahoo, I was check it. but on gmail there no email receive. I try again and again but no receive on inbox or spam.